# Can you overcool an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, hardware, temperature

My iPhone sits in my car on a holder that clips into one of the air vents.

In the winter, I don't want hot air from the heater to make my iPhone hotter, so I close that single vent.

In the summer, I allow the cold air from the air con through the vent, which certainly counteracts any heat that the iPhone might produce, but I'm wondering whether there's any likely damage from excessive cooling, particularly on the (increasing number of) days that are over 30˚C, and the air con is on full blast.

Apple's support page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201678 says:

> Use iOS devices where the ambient temperature is between 0º and 35º C
> (32º to 95º F). Low- or high-temperature conditions might cause the
> device to change its behavior to regulate its temperature. Using an
> iOS device in very cold conditions outside of its operating range
> might temporarily shorten battery life and could cause the device to
> turn off. Battery life will return to normal when you bring the device
> back to higher ambient temperatures.

I don't think I'm subjecting it to 'very cold conditions outside of its operating range'. Assuming that the cooling effects are above freezing point, are there any dangers?

Or might cooling have a beneficial effect? (The battery does seem to last longer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt your aircon would be much below 16 - 18°C core temperature, and would actually be drier than the ambient air.

I don't see a problem.

I suppose the direct answer to your question title would be, "Yes, but not with car aircon"